# Cancel unconfirmed transaction

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, multibit

I sent 2.2 bitcoins using the old version of multibit application (0.5.18)

The commission is not calculated correctly. Therefore, the transaction can be confirmed forever.

What can I do to cancel a transaction?

I read about a "double-spend" and other solutions to the problem, but what should I do step by step (because I used a multibit).

Try to export keys and install bitcoin core?

Is the transaction self-canceled if I do nothing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)